# Trying to get an alphabetized list of products with names that begin with 'dog'

Tags: sql, ms-access

I’m trying to get an alphabetized list of products with names that begin with dog. Trying to Order By product name, using the A_Products Table

See screenshot of A_Products Table:
[image]

**My Sample Code**

SELECT ProductName

FROM A_Products

WHERE ProductName LIKE 'DOG%'

ORDER BY ProductName ASC

.........

Thank you, 
Paul :-)

Answer (score 2):

MS Access uses `*` for `LIKE` not `%`:

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM A_Products
WHERE ProductName LIKE "DOG*"
ORDER BY ProductName ASC
```